# Remove special characters

Tags: php, special-characters, hotlinking

I'm protecting links with the following function

```
 function encode_html5($str){
      return '#'.preg_replace("/0{1}([0-9a-f]{3})/i", "$1", implode("", unpack("H*", iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-16BE", $str))));
 }
```

The problem is some special characters generated, I opened the file with `vim :set list` and at the beginning there are `$` then lots of `@` and finally `#` which is where my link should start.

I've tried lots of different things but, nothing seems to work. What i've tried:

```
$container = encode_html5($container);
$container = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $container);
$container = str_replace('$', '', $container);
$container = str_replace('#', '', $container);
$container = htmlentities($container);
$container = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/",'', $container);
```

pre encode_html5 $container

```
{"playlist":[{"comment":"000-u9f82u9fe1u9fe2u3bebu9fa5u9fadu9fa8u9fa5","file":"http://test.com/users/music/albums/11072013/dnbrn.to/000-u9f82u9fe1u9fe2u3bebu9fa5u9fadu9fa8u9fa5.mp3"},{"comment":"001-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_1","file":"http://test.com/users/music/albums/11072013/dnbrn.to/001-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_1.mp3"},{"comment":"002-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_2","file":"http://test.com/users/music/albums/11072013/dnbrn.to/002-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_2.mp3"},{"comment":"003-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_3","file":"http://test.com/users/music/albums/11072013/dnbrn.to/003-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_3.mp3"},{"comment":"004-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_4","file":"http://test.com/users/music/albums/11072013/dnbrn.to/004-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_4.mp3"},{"comment":"005-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_5","file":"http://test.com/users/music/albums/11072013/dnbrn.to/005-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_5.mp3"},{"comment":"006-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_6","file":"http://test.com/users/music/albums/11072013/dnbrn.to/006-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_6.mp3"},{"comment":"007-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_7","file":"http://test.com/users/music/albums/11072013/dnbrn.to/007-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_7.mp3"},{"comment":"008-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_8","file":"http://test.com/users/music/albums/11072013/dnbrn.to/008-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_8.mp3"},{"comment":"009-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_9","file":"http://test.com/users/music/albums/11072013/dnbrn.to/009-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_9.mp3"},{"comment":"010-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_10","file":"http://test.com/users/music/albums/11072013/dnbrn.to/010-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_10.mp3"},{"comment":"011-u9f83u9fabu9fa0u9fa2u9fa0_11",
...
```

post encode_html5 $container

```
$ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ @ #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
```

Comment: Whats the problem with using `htmlentities()`?

Comment: my links are in json format

Comment: Could you post the original value of `$container`, what you want to get, and what you're actually getting instead?

Comment: But you say your problem is with the beginning of the file. It sounds like this may be totally unrelated to the way you protect the links elsewhere in the file.

Comment: I tried your function, I don't get anything like that. My result starts with `#07b02207006c06107...`

Comment: open with vim and : set list. you'll see it. when you set the `: set list` click button up

Comment: I don't use vim, I don't know what that does. I'm just using `var_dump($container)` in PHP.

Comment: that way it won't show you special characters.

Comment: Why are you parsing a `JSON` string rather than converting to an object and parsing the values?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to understand specifically what you are trying to do, but I think I've had a similar problem recently.

Try http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php and it's associated decode function right before the data is transferred.

You can also try html_entity_decode after using json_encode.

The last thing I'd offer is to json_encode your string before echoing.